# Creating a sum of a column on records in Big Query and storing as a materialized view

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a sum of a column called `COUNT`, but the sum should only allow a guid to be counted once. That means if a column has the same guid as another, only sum the count one time for that guid. Ideally I want to then add the counts for that whole day

Consider the following

| ID | COUNT | GUID | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | HJK123 | 08/07/23 |
| 2 | 10 | HJK123 | 08/07/23 |
| 3 | 10 | LKJ123 | 08/07/23 |
| 4 | 5 | BTW123 | 08/07/23 |
| 5 | 5 | BTW123 | 08/07/23 |
| 6 | 5 | BTW123 | 08/07/23 |
| 7 | 5 | QRE123 | 08/07/23 |
| 8 | 5 | OLP123 | 08/07/23 |
| 9 | 3 | HTE123 | 08/07/23 |
| 10 | 3 | HTE123 | 08/07/23 |

Ideally I want a base table to remove dupes with the same GUID and then create a materialized view on that. Big Query doesn't allow creating materialized views on materialized views so I am not sure what to do. I really just want to dedupe my base table to create a materialized view on. Any suggestions?

| ID | COUNT | GUID | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | HJK123 | 08/07/23 |
| 3 | 10 | LKJ123 | 08/07/23 |
| 4 | 5 | BTW123 | 08/07/23 |
| 7 | 5 | QRE123 | 08/07/23 |
| 8 | 5 | OLP123 | 08/07/23 |
| 9 | 3 | HTE123 | 08/07/23 |

In the perfect world, what I am trying to end up with is

| COUNT | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 38 | 08/07/23 |

I have tried subqueries, WITH clauses, grouping, separate materialized views, views. I feel like I have exhausted every solution to mind.

Comment: What do you want the Unique key to be? The GUID? The GUID plus the date, combined? Or, the GUID plus the date plus the count?

Comment: Why do you think that BigQuery doesn't support sub-queries?

Comment: Why does the final result have an id column, and why is the value 1?

Comment: Big query doesn't support sub queries in materialized views in many instances. 
I just edited the post to include more info.

Comment: We can ignore the ID, and I apologize for including that. I just want the GUIDs deduped and counted one time and then sum up for that date

Comment: If multiple rows have the same GUID but different dates, which date/row should be kept? If multiple rows have the same GUID and the same date, but different counts, which count/row should be kept?

Comment: That's a great question. They would actually be almost complete duplicates, so we can trust that the date and the guid would be the same. I just want to only count one instance of the guid